# Criar layout para aplicações PHP e .NET

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, .net

Trabalho em um órgão público e temos inúmeras aplicações web em **PHP** e **.NET**.

Estou trabalhando em um layout padrão para que mantenhamos a identidade visual em todos os sistemas.

Existe alguma forma (ferramenta/*framework*/API) em que cada desenvolvedor, independente da linguagem consiga usar?

A estrutura que montamos é: `Header`, `PostCss`, `Navbar`, `Content`, `Sidebar`, `PostScript` e `Footer`.

No **PHP** por exemplo, eu dou um `include` no arquivo e pronto. Ainda consigo personalizar algumas variáveis como `$tituloPagina`.

Ainda gostaríamos de criar seções como no Blade do Laravel, onde consigo usar `@yield` e `@section`.

A ideia era criar uma API e que no URL, o programador já passasse o valor das variáveis e então montar o *layout* com o JSON do resultado, ou algo do tipo, por exemplo: `?tituloPagina=loremipsum&corpoPagina=centralizado`.

Comment: Não sei se pode te ajudar, mas eu costumo utilizar framework para casos parecidos com o descrito. Uso bootestrap ou o materialize

Comment: Você ainda não escolheu uma resposta. Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solução para isso é mais ou menos o que já está na pergunta.

Claro que o ideal é não usar várias tecnologias, se o fez ainda seria melhor mudar tudo isso, mas pode ser inviável mudar tudo agora, então tem que mudar pelo menos uma parte.

Cada tecnologia vai tentar fazer o melhor possível dentro da sua filosofia, não vai se preocupar em funcionar com outras tão díspares.

## Single Page Application

Dependendo do caso é possível fazer o *layout* todo no cliente, usando [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Existem diversos *frameworks* disputando o mercado (o estado da popularidade é a minha percepção no momento da resposta, não tome como informação absoluta):

- [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) é ou era o mais popular atualmente
- [React](http://facebook.github.io/react/) é ou era o que mais cresce
- [Vuejs](http://vuejs.org/) é usado por muitos e aqui encerra a primeira divisão :)
- [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) ainda tem forte participação
- [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) é uma opção
- [ExtJS](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) tem recursos que ajudam
- [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) já teve mais força
- [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) ainda tem adeptos
- [Canjs](http://canjs.com/) corre por fora
- [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/) pode interessar certas pessoas
- [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org) é mais uma opção
- [Mercury](https://github.com/Raynos/mercury) vale dar uma olhada

Se quiser usar C# no cliente pode agora usar o [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101).

## Web API

A outra forma é deixar que uma destas tecnologias cuide do *layout* e a outra seja usada só como API desta, conforme dito na pergunta. Não tem muito segredo, não precisa nada especial.

O .NET tem algo que facilite o uso do ASP.NET com [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). A versão nova integrou esta tecnologia dentro do ASP.NET Core.

Desconheço alguma ferramenta universalmente aceita para o PHP. Mas no fundo é só uma padronização de como o dado deve ser acessado.

Não existem ferramentas que ajudem padronizar entre tecnologias diferentes. O máximo que pode ser feito é criar seus próprios padrões, montar uma biblioteca e um mecanismo de gabarito que possa usar nas duas tecnologias, mas duvido que o trabalho compense. Se fosse algo bom a se fazer alguém já teria criado algo como produto.

Se tiver dúvidas específicas do que precisa faça perguntas específicas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que você descreve, o que você precisa é de um template engine no lado cliente

Para assim então, utilizar em ambos server(php e .net) recebendo apenas os dados de uma API e sim, podendo customizar

Um dos mais famosos(eu uso) é o Handlebars.js

Comment: Show. Vou dar uma lida e procurar saber mais sobre esse. É isso que eu queria, alguém que já tenha feito algo parecido, para dizer exatamente o que foi usado e se atendeu os requisitos. valeu.

Comment: @buback como o Daniel citou, poderá ter problemas com indexação. Também não é necessário criar rotas no cliente, conforme também citaram

Answer (score 3):

A proposta atual é o uso de "javascript template engine".

Há diversos frameworks como o angular.js, handlebars.js, mustache.js, Jquery template, pure.js, dust,js, emblem.js, marckup.js, plates.js, json2html, dentre dezenas.

A maior dificuldade que poderá ter é quando precisar de compatibilidade com mecanismos de busca.

Os bots de busca não compilam JavaScript. Uma implicância nisso é, por exemplo, quando o website que carrega o corpo de uma página por ajax. Como o bot não executa o JavaScript, não conseguirá sequer fazer as requisições, a menos que faça adaptações específicas.

Comment: +1Os bots de busca não compilam JavaScript

Comment: @durtto, por ser sistema, não preciso que as páginas sejam indexadas. Na verdade a maioria é serviço interno dos servidores.

Comment: Eu utilizo o framework Extjs, a curva de aprendizagem é regular. Execelente ferramenta totalmente voltada para criação de sistemas. O Sistema de classes é incrível,  é uma poderosa forma de programar em javascript. Atente-se para a questão da licença, caso tenha interesse nele. Veja que @bigwon atualizou a resposta dele com vários exemplos de **frameworks** existentes que ajudam muito.

Answer (score 2):

Complementa a resposta do `@bignow`, você precisa montar uma estratégia e estabalecer qual padrão de ferramentas deve usar.
Deve-se fazer perguntas a si mesmo(e/ou a equipe) à respeito de como agir, já que atualmente existem as mais diversas formas de fazer o que queres. Orgãos públicos geralmente fazem isso muito bem, digo isso pois já implantei aplicativos contidos em [SPB - Portal Software Público](https://softwarepublico.gov.br) e vários deles utilizam uma estratégia de criação de layouts visando visando uma padronização.

Veja um exemplo simples, que remete à ideia levantada por você. Utilizando-se da tecnologia javascript, especificadamente a biblioteca [`pure.js`](http://pure.github.io/pure/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PURE Unobtrusive Rendering Engine</title>
  <script src="http://pure.github.io/pure/libs/pure.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   <!-- HTML template -->
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <script>
    var data = {
      animals:[
        {name: 'mouse'},
        {name: 'cat'},
        {name: 'bird'},
        {name: 'dog'}
      ]
    };
    var directive = {
      'li':{
        'animal<-animals':{ //for each entry in animales name the element 'animal'
          'span': 'animal.name' //the dot selector, means the current node (here a LI)
        }
      }
    };
    $p( 'ul' ).render( data, directive );
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```